# Comparing groups using SPSS

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, panel-data

I have a dataset with 2 measures that were tested over 30 time points. I have a two groups of people who have both measures at all 30 time points. How do I compare the groups using SPSS?

Comment: Are you asking a statistics question or an SPSS question?